# I can't figure out the word for all the -isms (like sexism, racism, etc) (help!)

Tags: terminology

the word minorities doesn't really work because I mean the actual term for **all** the **isms** so I can say ____ like sexism...

Comment: This question isn't very clear to me. For an overview of how to ask word-request questions on this site, please read https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info

Comment: We are all in that 'minority' since we all belong to an -ism of one kind or another. Therefore we are not a minority. We are diverse humans.

Answer (score 2):

Try "ideologies," or perhaps specifically discriminatory ideologies. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/-ism